# Get Remote Desktop Status of Cloud Service(classic) using Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension or any cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm new to powershell and Azure cmdlets(ASM or ARM). I'm trying to list all the cloud service along with its Remote Desktop status(Enabled or Disabled). I'm able to get the cloud service details using Get-AzureService or Get-AzureDeployment cmdlets.

To get the Remote Desktop Status, I'm using this cmdlet Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension but it is not returning anything.

```
Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension -ServiceName mycloudservicename -Slot Production
```

Few observation from azure portal settings:

1. The "Remote Desktop"(RD) blade under cloud service is having a Role
   for which currently RD is disabled for both the
   slots(Production/Staging). Not sure if this
   Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension cmdlet work only when the RD
   is enabled.
2. The "Roles and Instances" blade has a Role with 2 instances, both
   of which doesn't have the Connect button enabled as the RD is not
   enabled.
3. I'm seeing "Disabled" node under Extensions blade. I'm not sure if
   the extension has to be enabled or install/get any extension. I
   tried something like below but that also not returning anything.

   ```
      Get-AzureServiceExtension -ServiceName mycloudservicename -Slot "Production" 
      -ExtensionName "RDP" -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions"
   ```

Any thoughts what i'm missing here to get Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension working? Or let me know if any other easy way to get the RD status. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension` works only when the RD is enabled, I can reproduce your issue on my side, just enable the RD, it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your testing. Unfortunately all my cloud services are having it disabled, if I enable this the service will get restarted or I need to attach a cert at cloud service level, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop-new-portal. So to test this I've to create a new sample service and enable the RD in that. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Works fine, thanks Joy. Get-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtension doesn't return anything if the RD is disabled. Looks this is by cmdlet design.